# Number guessing game play again

Tags: java

Im having problems making my game play again. I have a boolean variable but when i enter yes or no the program just ends. Im having trouble making it restart the //Game loop. My boolean doesn't execute anything at the moment

```
    //Game

    System.out.println("Pick a number between 1-100");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
    int round = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    int win = 0;

    while(win == 0)
    {
        round++;
        System.out.println("Round " + round);

        System.out.print("What is your first guess? ");
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        count++;

        if (guess == number)
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("You win in " + count + " guess.");
                ++win;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (guess > number)
        {
            System.out.println("That's too high. Try again: ");
        }
        else if (guess < number)
        {
            System.out.println("That's too low. Try again: ");
        }

    }


    //Ask to play again
    boolean isValidAnswer;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Would you like to play again (yes/no)? ");
        String playAgain = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();
        isValidAnswer= playAgain.equals("YES") || playAgain.equals("NO");
        if(! isValidAnswer)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Please enter yes or no");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }while(!isValidAnswer);
}
```

}

Comment: Seems like you want another loop on `playAgain` (you **can** put a loop, or ***two***, in another loop), also seems like you'll need more *scope* for that.

Comment: Try using TDD ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the `round` before the user wins the guess which is incorrect, so place it inside the `if` block which means that it will be incremented only when the guess is right as shown below, also initialize the `round` to 1 during the start of the game.

```
    int round = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    int win = 0;
    boolean showRound=true;
    while(win == 0) {
        if(showRound) {
            System.out.println("Round " + round);
        }
        System.out.print("What is your first guess? ");
        guess = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());//Use scanner.nextLine()
        count++;

        if (guess == number) {
            showRound = true;
            round++;//Increment the round only after win
            System.out.println("You win in " + count + " guess.");
            ++win;
            break;
        } else if (guess > number) {
            System.out.println("That's too high. Try again: ");
            showRound=false;
        } else if (guess < number) {
            System.out.println("That's too low. Try again: ");
            showRound=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i do this after every attempt it keeps bringing up "round 1"  after i enter a number too high or too low. How can i make it so that it doesn't bring up round 1 and "What is your first guess?" after every incorrect guess

Comment: You need to use `System.out.println("Round " + round+":");`

Comment: I mean it keeps looping back to "What is your first guess? ". How can i keep it all under the round loop. For instance: Round 1. What is your first guess? **32** Too high, Try again: **23** Too low, Try again: **30**

Comment: So, you want Round1 to appear only once, am I right?

Comment: Correct. I would need to change its position in the code?

Comment: Look above, add `if(count==0)`

Comment: Ah i see, thank you very much that worked. Now all i need to do is get my **playAgain** boolean working. I need to make it loop back to the game, when i enter yes or no nothing happens of course

Comment: I updated code above, have look, use `showRound=true;`

Comment: I'm not following